# Returning the Cell location of specific value in a separate Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

To clarify. I have 1 spreadsheet I am creating the VBA in. When the Macro runs, I want the code to find a specific value in a separate WorkBook sheet and return the location of the value in the other WorkBook.

My initial thought was to use HLookUp, however that will only return the value, not the location of the value. My next thought was to use the Find function, but I can't get it to run. The error I get is: Run-time error "438': Object doesn't support this property or method

```
startValue = enrollBook.Sheets("Pop-FY").Range("D:Z"). _
Applications.WorksheetFunction. _
Find(What:=FYString, LookIn:=xlValues)
```

enrollBook is the other workbook. 
startValue is supposed to be the location of the found value in the other spreadsheet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a weird way of calling a function & formatting you've got there, I first even thought that code was invalid.

First, you are confusing `Range.Find` with `Application.WorksheetFunction.Find`. You need the `Range` one, but are calling the other one.
Second, the error is because it's `Application`, not `Applications`.
Third, you will need a `Set`:

```
Set startValue = enrollBook.Sheets("Pop-FY").Range("D:Z").Find(What:=FYString, LookIn:=xlValues)
```

Comment: Ok it ran correctly. However, after execution startValue equaled the value I was looking for (FYString), not the location of FYString in enrollBook.

Comment: @dancran How did you check that? By hovering the cursor over it? Then it would show you the `Value` property.

Comment: Yes, by hovering over it. However I just did a quick check using what was said above (startValue.Address) and it gave my the location. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```
Dim sTest           As String
Dim oRange          As Range

Set oRange = Worksheets(1).Range("A1:Z10000").Find("Test", lookat:=xlPart)
MsgBox oRange.Address
```

I tested this, but you need to change your parameters.

Comment: You can put the address in a string by declaring dim sTest as string and defining sTest = oRange.address

Comment: Thank you Kim. The address was a big help for me.